# Deleting variables in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I have not been able to find anyone previously asking this :

How do you let go of a variable in OCaml ? Python has `del` and I assume OCaml has a similar function, but I cannot find it. Is it even possible to delete a variable ?

If not, then how does one manage variables in OCaml ?

Comment: What would be the use case for that?

Comment: This seems like an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/), btw. You're asking about a specific solution rather than an actual problem.

Comment: @glennsl I guess my formulation does make it seem like an XY problem, I will rephrase.

Comment: If you provided a piece of code in which you'd need to delete a variable, it'd be easier to give you an answer. As OCaml is very different from python, maybe you will never need such function while writing OCaml code

Comment: @Butanium I don't need to delete any variables for now, I only asked for clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I it not possible to let go of a variable in OCaml with a keyword. However you may use the variable scope in such a way :

```ml
let a = b in
print_endline a ;
...
```

Is different from :

```ml
( let a = b in
  print_endline a ) ;
...
```

In the first one, you may access `a` inside `...`, but not in the second.
You can also shadow a variable :

```ml
let a = b in
print_endline a ;
let a = () in
...
```

Inside `...`, it will be impossible to access the original `a`: there is a new variable named `a`, the old one is "deleted" (the correct term being shadowed).

OCaml also allows you to declare variables anywhere, not matter how "small" the expression :

```ml
print_endline (let a = b in a) ;
...
```

is perfectly valid, and `a` is only defined inside the `( )`. The printed value will be the same than in the first example.

Comment: Does that mean variables created in the global scope are never deallocated ? If yes, it seems like a potential memory leak risk to me.

Comment: I don't think there are `global variables` in `OCaml`, unless someone corrects me!!!

Comment: Variables bound in the global scope are always alive (they can always be acceded), thus they cannot leak memory by definition.

Comment: @octachron Maybe "Leak" is not the proper term then. But you did answer my question, it seems like the using global variables in general is ill-advised since it fills memory that cannot be freed until a full exit.

Comment: I think global variables are generally ill-advised for other reasons, but not because of memory use. You can for example use a ref cell, i.e. `let big_data : big_data option ref = Some ...`. By setting it to `None`, and also not referencing the data elsewhere, it will be garbage collected automatically.

Comment: You don't "manage" variables (or "bindings" rather), you manage the values that variables refer to.

Comment: @glennsl Okay that makes sense, just wanted to make sure I would be able to let go of big data sets provided I'm pretty sure we have some data science lined up and we haven't been told what language that will be done in

Comment: @Crysambrosia It is true that a global variable is never freed. This is for good reason : if it was, this could allow the runtime failure of accessing a deleted value. OCaml is designed in such a way that there are the least runtime failures, and only at places where you would expect them. It is true that freeing values is useful, and there is a system to that, but it is a compile-time system, and its called scope. So if you have some big data only useful during a certain computation, put the whole computation in a function and make sure that the data does not escape.

Comment: Mutability and `option` is a possibility, but it is not "ocamlic" : it allows for runtime failures (mitigated by the fact that you need to handle them by matching on your option). It is allowed, and if your problem really is difficult to express with scope, use it, but scope is the way to go if possible.

Comment: @Crysambrosia It's worse. Global variables are never collected by the garbage colletor at all. The resources are simply freeed by the operating system on exit. Finalizers for global variables are never executed.

Answer (score 2):

The closest counterpart of a Python variable in OCaml is a reference (which is a mutable field of a record). In Python, you commonly delete a variable to let the GC do it work and collect the variable contents as soon as possible. You could do this in OCaml as well by assigning a new value to the reference. Commonly, you would use the `option` type or some other container to store values in references, e.g.,

```
let foo = ref None
let () = 
  foo := Some big_data_structure; (* assigning *)
  foo := None (* deleting *)
```

or

```
let foo = ref []
let () =
  foo := [some; huge; list];
  foo := []
```

If we will speak about immutable variables, then you can also speed up their collection by making sure that their lifetime is as small as possible. Therefore it is a common practice to bind a result of a transformation of an immutable value to the same variable as it was before (aka shadowing, rebinding, hiding), e.g.,

```
let names = ["ahura"; "bahman"; "dana"; "ervin"]
let names = List.map String.capitalize names
(* previous names are no longer accessible here, so GC can collect them *)
```

Here we made sure that the old `names` are not accessible so that the GC can collect them in the nearest minor collection.